# send table through email android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I am pretty new to Android.
So I have this custom ListView with just 2 simple TextViews side by side, now once I press a button, I want the contents of this ListView to be sent via email in a Tabular format. Now other than creating a pdf annd sending that as an attachment which requires libraries and other file handling hassle, is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of most emails are html so I would suggest placing it there in an html table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>TextView1</th>
    <th>TextView2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value1</td>
    <td>value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```